# Unable to link my django to mysql database (Form)

Tags: python, mysql, django

can someone help me with my code? Why is it not working?

My views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            fullname = form.cleaned_data.get('fullname')
            emailaddress = form.cleaned_data.get('emailaddress')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    fullname = forms.CharField(label='fullname', max_length=100)
    emailaddress = forms.EmailField(label='emailaddress', max_length=150)
    password = forms.CharField(label='password', max_length=100)
```

Thanks a lot!

Can't seem to connect the inputed data into the db...

Comment: Do you have a model? If so, please include it.

Comment: Any log something ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to save data to database by using `Django Forms` then its better to use `ModelForm`. Instead of inheriting the class from `forms.Form` use `ModelForm` for example

```
 class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = < model class >
      fields = ['required fields']
```

change according to your use case. for more information check the documentation [django modelform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/)

If you wish to implement a custom user authentication model (both registration and login) use bellow link to know more.
[extending user model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try another method also

```
  userdetails=modelname.objects.create(fullname=fullname,
  emailaddress=emailaddress)
  userdetails.set_password(request.POST['password'])
  userdetails.save()
```

If you want to use same method, share your error message